# Android INSTALL_RECEIVER Broadcast Listener gets null referrer

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, referrer

I am attempting to get the install referrer in an INSTALL_RECEIVER broadcast listener. I receive the event without any issues however the referrer string is always null. My manifest includes:

```
<service android:name="com.myname.myapp.InstallReceiver"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.myname.myapp.InstallReceiver" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

my BroascastReceiver is:

```
public class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static String TAG = "INSTALL_RECEIVER";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received install event");
        String referrer = "";
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {
            referrer = extras.getString("referrer");
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Referer is: " + referrer);
    }
}
```

and to test I am using the following commands:

```
adb shell
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.myname.myapp/com.myname.myapp.InstallReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"
```

can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? The receiver is triggered because I get the following output in LogCat:

```
Received install event
Referer is null
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `-e` instead of `--es`, though AFAIK both should work. Also, watch your `r` count, as in your `Log.d()` call, you have `Referer`, which is missing an `r`. While that's OK (it's just a log message), if the code you are running isn't exactly what you have here in the question, it's possible that you are missing an `r` elsewhere.

Comment: Its working! You are right I must have made a typo and it must have been in the "am broadcast" command (the version I pasted here was from the reference I was using, not copied from my terminal, because it was being a complete pain to copy).

Comment: I am having same issue I get the broadcast but getting "intent.getData()" as "null"

Comment: Try something like:
`Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();  
 for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
     Object value = extras.get(key);
     Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s (%s)", key, value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));
 }`

to see what is there.